# Reactify Django or separated frontend and backend

Tags: django, reactjs, reactify

I would like to know why sould reactify Django or why should we use separated django backend and react frontend.
which implementation is more scalelable
I hope you could help me ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way (to separate backend & frontend) helps you in different ways.

1. You can separate backend & frontend developer teams. Thus, you can easily scale your developer teams. It's much easier to hire somebody highly skilled in **React** than somebody skilled in both **React** & **Django**.
2. It's clean! You have separated the logic & UI.
3. You can have multiple clients with the same backend engine. Imagine a day that you want to have a mobile application with the same backend logic.

and there are many other reasons.

But you can keep your speed in development if you don't do that. Many startups don't separate themselves and just do the front-end inside template engines like Django's. This helps to be quicker in the development process. You can hire Fullstack developers and everything goes faster than two or multiple teams focusing on their technology.